# Using tax_query creates a 1 = 0 or 1 = 1 in $wp_query->request

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, tax-query

This is my first attempt at modifying the main query using the `pre_get_posts` action/filter

This is the function currently hooked to it:

```
function advanced_product_search_filter($query)
{
  if(!is_admin() &&
     is_main_query() && 
     is_search() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product')
  {
    $keyword = $_GET['s'];

    if($_GET['exactly'])
      $keyword = $_GET['s'] . ' "'. $_GET['exactly'] . '"';

    if($_GET['without'])
    {
      $excluded = exclude_product_keyword_search($_GET['without'], 
                    $_GET['pname'],
                    $_GET['pcode']
                  );
      $query->set('post__not_in', $excluded);
    }

    if($_GET['pname'])
      $query->set('s', $keyword);
    else
      $query->set('s', '');

    if($_GET['pcode'])
    {
      $tax_queries = $query->get('tax_query');
      $tax_queries[] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_ordering-code',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => array($keyword),
          'operator' => 'LIKE'
        )
      );
      $query->set('tax_query', $tax_queries);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a plugin built on top of a `WooCommerce` installation. So basically this function *tries* to support searching a `WooCommerce` product either through the standard search (title and content) or an attribute search on a custom attribute called `Ordering Code` which is `pa_ordering-code` in the `term_taxonomy` table

Other parts of the code works fine, I can modify the `s` and `post__not_in` vars without any problems, but if I try to use the `tax_query` it, the query seems to break down.

To give you an idea, when I try this:

```
?s=foo&post_type=product&pname=1&pcode=1&without=non&exactly=foo+bar
```

dumping the `WHERE` clause, I see this:

```
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (219) 
AND 0 = 1 
AND 
(
  (
    (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo%') OR 
    (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo%')
  ) AND (
    (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo bar%') OR 
    (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo bar%')
  )
) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND
( 
  (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND
    CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search')
  ) 
)
```

Notice the `AND 0 = 1`? When I dump the `JOIN` clause, I become sure that the `tax_query` parameter isn't being interpreted properly since I only see the `postmeta` table in there. No `terms`, `term_relationships`, or `term_taxonomy` table.

And I also tried simply overwriting the existing `tax_query` (if there is one) by doing this:

```
$args = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_ordering-code',
    'field' => 'name',
    'terms' => array($keyword),
    'operator' => 'LIKE'
  )
);
$query->set('tax_query', $args);
```

But I still could not get it to work. Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The `0 = 1` happens when the terms don't exist.

You're creating a query for some set of terms. Before it can add the SQL to that main query, it first does a secondary query to get the term_id's for the relevant terms. If none are found, then it returns 0 = 1 instead, to shortcut the main query because no terms match the request.

Answer (score 0):

Check definition of your "pa_ordering-code" taxonomy.

It looks like you could have wrong value in "query_var" attribute.

This code could casue similar efect:

```
    register_taxonomy(...
        'query_var' => true,
    ));
```

If so, remove (or change) query_var part and check again.

Answer (score 0):

In your `tax_query`, try setting `field` to `term_taxonomy_id` and using `$term->term_taxonomy_id` instead of `$term->term_id`:

```php
        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_taxonomy_id,
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
```